# File upload returns null

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, uploadify

I am uploading a file in my ASP.NET MVC application using Uploadify.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {           
            List<string> validIDs, invalidIDs;
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            { //do something
            }
        }
```

Uploadify code (in a .ascx file):

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    $("#file_upload").uploadify({
        'uploader': '/Scripts/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script': '/XYZ/Upload',
        'cancelImg': '/Scripts/uploadify/cancel.png',
        'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;*.bmp;*.htm;*.html;*.zip',
        'fileDesc': '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;*.bmp;*.htm;*.html;*.zip',
        'auto': true,
        'multi': false,
        'sizeLimit': 1048576,   //1 MB
        'buttonText': 'Upload Files'
}
    });
});
```

The 'file' in the controller action is always returning NULL. What am I missing?

Comment: To help polish your debugging skills: You can trace HTTP requests using Fiddler and look under the hood that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace:

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
```

with:

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
```

`Uploadify` uses the `fileData` name by default. You could change that in the settings if you want like that: `fileDataName: 'file'`. Take a look at the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8019743/29407) as well.