# Uploadify with MVC4 not working. IO Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, flash, uploadify

i am using Uploadify version 3.1. when i try to upload a file , i am getting IO Error.

when i keep the debugger in action method, its not hitting.

I tried the following link but even thought the same error.

[Getting HTTP Error while using uploadify on Asp.net MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358223/getting-http-error-while-using-uploadify-on-asp-net-mvc-application)

Please suggest me .

**View**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/uploadify/uploadify.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="file_upload"></div>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@*    <script src="@Url.Content("~/uploadify/swfobject.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>*@
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/uploadify/jquery.uploadify-3.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'uploader': '@Url.Content("~/uploadify/uploadify.swf")',
            'flash_url': '@Url.Content("~/uploadify/uploadify.swf")',
            'fileObjName': 'fileData',
            'script': '@Url.Action("Upload", "Home")',
            'cancelImg': '@Url.Content("~/uploadify/cancel.png")',
            'folder': '@Url.Content("~/content/images")',
            'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
            'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
            'auto': true
        });    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**[Controller]**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
    }
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
{
    if (fileData != null && fileData.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/" + Path.GetFileName(fileData.FileName));
        fileData.SaveAs(fileName);
        return Json(true);
    }
    return Json(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'checkExisting': 'Content/uploadify/check-exists.php',
            'swf': '@Url.Content("~/uploadify/uploadify.swf")',
            'uploader': '@Url.Action("Upload", "Home")',
            'auto': false,
            'buttonText': 'Browse',
            'fileTypeExts': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.gif',
            'removeCompleted': false
         });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the folder rights of your folder where you're uploading files? you need to set permissions for that folder to IIS user and Network users as well

Answer (score 0):

Check your controller, action must be **AllowAnonymous**.