# Uploadify Script is not working when inside kohana controller

Tags: kohana, uploadify

Hello I am trying to implement the uploadify script in kohana 2.3.4, it works when i place the uploadify script on the root directory then point it out on my view file. But when I point the script to a controllr, it returns a http error. Below is the js script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
'uploader'  : '<?=url::base()?>uploadify/uploadify.swf',
'script'    : '<?=url::base()?>uploadify', /*Even tried     http://localhost/directory/uploadify*/
'cancelImg' : '<?=url::base()?>uploadify/cancel.png',
'folder'    : '<?=url::base().$directory?>',
'multi'       : true,
'removeCompleted' : false,
'auto'      : true
 });
 });
 // ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: What's the error you are receiving? Also, what does your uploadify controller look like?

Comment: HTTP error, same as the uploafiy script but the script is inside the controller

Comment: What does the HTTP error say?

Comment: Also, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877644/uploadify-show-error-message-from-http-response

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what error you were receiving but if your page requires authentication and controller not able to authenticate user then you can follow my solution.
Problem is that uploadify uses flash and there is bug in flash that it does not sent cookies to server.

I changed it at shown below to get it working.
in js (for kohana)

```js
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
    uploader: base_url+"upload/image?sess=<?php Session::instance()->id(); ?>",
});
```

and in plain php

```js
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
    uploader: base_url+"upload/image?sess=<?php session_id();?>",
});
```

and in kohana controller while reading authentication from session, initialize session as following

```php
  $sess_id = Arr::get($_GET,'sess',null);
  $sess = Session::instance(null,$sess_id);
```

or in plain php

```
session_name($_GET['sess']);
session_start();
```

in future if bug in flash is fixed then there will be no need to do this