# MVC 3 & Uploadify - how to show custom error message?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, uploadify

After uploading a file, before I save it on the disk, I'm doing some validation.

If something fails, I want to show my custom error message to the user. 
I've found something sililar here [Uploadify: show error message from HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877644/uploadify-show-error-message-from-http-response)

How to do this in MVC 3 ?

Answer (score 2):

Tony,

Taken straight from ab mvc3 app that I'm working on right now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initupLoadify() {
        $("#fileInput").uploadify({
            uploader: '@Url.Content("~/scripts/swf/uploadify.swf")',
            script: '@Url.Action("Upload", "Home")',
            cancelImg: '@Url.Content("~/Content/cancel.png")',
            auto: true,
            sizeLimit: 5500000,
            fileDataName: 'fileData',
            //scriptData: { 'propertyId': $("#PropertyID").val() },
            buttonText: 'Add Schedule',
            wmode: 'transparent',
            //buttonImg: '@Url.Content("~/Content/button.png")', // make nice gradient image for button
            onComplete: function (event, queueId, fileObj, response) {
                $("#msg").html(response);
                // do something
                setTimeout(2000, window.location = '@Url.Action("Index")' + '?id=' + response);
                return true;
            },
            onCancel: function (evt, queueId, fileObj, data) {
                $("#msg").html("<br />Operation cancelled");
                return true;
            },
            onOpen: function (evt, queueId, fileObj) {
                $("#msg").html("<br />Upload in progress");
                return true;
            },
            onError: function (event, queueId, fileObj, errorObj) {
                $("#msg").html(fileObj.name + " was not uploaded ");
                if (errorObj.status == 404)
                    $("#msg").html("Could not find upload script. Use a path relative to: " + "<?= getcwd() ?>");
                else if (errorObj.type === "HTTP")
                    $("#msg").html("error " + errorObj.type + ": " + errorObj.status);
                else if (errorObj.type === "File Size")
                    $("#msg").html(fileObj.name + " " + errorObj.type + " Limit: " + errorObj.info / 1000 + " KB");
                else
                    $("#msg").html("error " + errorObj.type + ": " + errorObj.text);
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

hope this helps

Comment: I've seen the similar codes, but it only shows the data of the file. But what if I want to show the message what exactly 'happened on the server' ?

Comment: tony - i see what your saying (re controller/service layer code, tho wasn't aware of this from the question). i've not had occassion to deal with that, but you've got my 'research' head on now, so will have a dig

Comment: I think it's time to change that plugin to something else

Comment: I'm using uploadify 3.1.1 and do not have an `onComplete` method available to me.  The `onUploadComplete` method does not pass the same parameters as you have outlined here.  Did you get this working on this version of uploadify?

Comment: hi webnet, i've not used the 3.1.1 version unfortunately. let me know how you've fared tho.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an MVC 3 [example](http://www.uploadify.com/forum/#/discussion/7098/mvc-3-razor-experience/p1).

If you're using versions 3.0+ use [onUploadComplete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13396695/1524303) instead of onComplete (realize their parameters differ).